# Custom Facebook button issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

My custom facebook like button works perfetly, but some weeks ago it broke.
It has transparent png background, but now the transparency isn't working.
See here(footer):frissbuzafu.hu

Please help me to find, what is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your button is two big for the image because when you scroll over the white part your still able to click button where asit should be only over the image part.